# Configure URL goals inside a wizard iframe that contains different urls

Tags: zend-framework, google-analytics

I am starting to use google analytics, and my question is the following. 
I'm trying to set up different url goals, but the problem is that i have a sign up process inside an iframe, like a wizard. For google analytics, all the process happens in the same view, but inside the iframe, the url is all time changing.
I need help both to configure my goals in admin panel and what do i have to do in the code. I'm working with Zend framework.

Comment: any help will be so usefull

Answer (score 0):

Add the standard tracking code in the ifram html.

If your iframe is on the same domain, it works fine.

If not, see the explaination on [the doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite?hl=fr#trackingIFrames) :

> use JavaScript to load the iFrame and pass in the cookie information using the _getLinkerURL() method

```
_gaq.push(function() {
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
    iframe.src = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl('http://www.my-example-iframecontent.com/');
});
```